# How to select only rows where at least one value has changed from the previous row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I have a table that is tracking values as snapshots every day, how can I only select the rows where at least one value changed per ID, not including the date of course. The first row per ID should always be included in the result too.

For example, with this table:

```
id    phone_number    email          date
1     12345           a@gmail.com    2020-01-01
1     12345           a@gmail.com    2020-01-02
1     23456           a@gmail.com    2020-01-03
1     34567           a@gmail.com    2020-01-04
1     34567           a@gmail.com    2020-01-05
1     45678           a@gmail.com    2020-01-06
1     45678           a@gmail.com    2020-01-07
2     56789           b@gmail.com    2020-01-01
2     56789           b@gmail.com    2020-01-02
2     56789           c@gmail.com    2020-01-03
2     67890           c@gmail.com    2020-01-04
2     67890           c@gmail.com    2020-01-05
3     78901           d@gmail.com    2020-01-01
3     78901           d@gmail.com    2020-01-02
3     78901           d@gmail.com    2020-01-03
```

would return this result:

```
id    phone_number    email          date
1     12345           a@gmail.com    2020-01-01
1     23456           a@gmail.com    2020-01-03
1     34567           a@gmail.com    2020-01-04
1     45678           a@gmail.com    2020-01-06
2     56789           b@gmail.com    2020-01-01
2     56789           c@gmail.com    2020-01-03
2     67890           c@gmail.com    2020-01-04
3     78901           d@gmail.com    2020-01-01
```

Comment: Can you please check the solution and help approve and upvote in case it worked for you .. will appreciate that

Comment: Can u pls help accept the answer in case if the solution worked for you ?

Comment: @dsk If you can translate my SQL answer into PySpark functions, I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You need to use window function with row_number() and take only first value-

## Create the DF Here

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,12345,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-01"),
                           (1,12345,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-02"),
                           (1,23456,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-03"),
                           (1,34567,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-04"),
                           (1,34567,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-05"),
                           (1,45678,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-06"),
                           (1,45678,"a@gmail.com","2020-01-07"),
                           (2,56789,"b@gmail.com","2020-01-01"),
                           (2,56789,"b@gmail.com","2020-01-02"),
                           (2,56789,"c@gmail.com","2020-01-03"),
                           (2,67890,"c@gmail.com","2020-01-04"),
                           (2,67890,"c@gmail.com","2020-01-05"),
                           (3,78901,"d@gmail.com","2020-01-01"),
                           (3,78901,"d@gmail.com","2020-01-02"),
                           (3,78901,"d@gmail.com","2020-01-03"),
                           ],[ "id","phone_number","email","date"])
df.show()
```

## Output

```
+---+------------+-----------+----------+
| id|phone_number|      email|      date|
+---+------------+-----------+----------+
|  1|       12345|a@gmail.com|2020-01-01|
|  1|       12345|a@gmail.com|2020-01-02|
|  1|       23456|a@gmail.com|2020-01-03|
|  1|       34567|a@gmail.com|2020-01-04|
|  1|       34567|a@gmail.com|2020-01-05|
|  1|       45678|a@gmail.com|2020-01-06|
|  1|       45678|a@gmail.com|2020-01-07|
|  2|       56789|b@gmail.com|2020-01-01|
|  2|       56789|b@gmail.com|2020-01-02|
|  2|       56789|c@gmail.com|2020-01-03|
|  2|       67890|c@gmail.com|2020-01-04|
|  2|       67890|c@gmail.com|2020-01-05|
|  3|       78901|d@gmail.com|2020-01-01|
|  3|       78901|d@gmail.com|2020-01-02|
|  3|       78901|d@gmail.com|2020-01-03|
+---+------------+-----------+----------+
```

## Logic Here

```
_w = W.partitionBy("id","phone_number","email").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("rnk", F.row_number().over(_w))
df = df.filter(F.col("rnk") ==F.lit(1))
df = df.orderBy("id", "phone_number")
df.show()
+---+------------+-----------+----------+---+
| id|phone_number|      email|      date|rnk|
+---+------------+-----------+----------+---+
|  1|       12345|a@gmail.com|2020-01-01|  1|
|  1|       23456|a@gmail.com|2020-01-03|  1|
|  1|       34567|a@gmail.com|2020-01-04|  1|
|  1|       45678|a@gmail.com|2020-01-06|  1|
|  2|       56789|c@gmail.com|2020-01-03|  1|
|  2|       56789|b@gmail.com|2020-01-01|  1|
|  2|       67890|c@gmail.com|2020-01-04|  1|
|  3|       78901|d@gmail.com|2020-01-01|  1|
+---+------------+-----------+----------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you - this nearly works, but it would miss rows if a value changes back to a value that was already seen before. For example, if you change row 5 fo the original dataframe to `(1, 12345, "a@gmail.com", "2020-01-05")`, this will be missing from the result. Can you think of any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working as a SQL query which I can run like this:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

df = spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT  a.*
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS row, id, phone_number, email, date FROM df) AS a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS row, id, phone_number, email, date FROM df) AS b
    ON a.row = b.row + 1 AND a.id = b.id 
    WHERE a.phone_number != b.phone_number OR b.phone_number IS NULL OR a.email != b.email OR b.email IS NULL
    """
)
```

This works fine, now I would just prefer to translate it into native PySpark code.

Comment: In order to convert this in PySpark I need to know the logic clearly and the expected output - How that looks like ?

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct  phone_number,email from table
```

Comment: I need the IDs and dates included too